# Is there a function for repositioning the tkinter window using the from tkinter import * module?

Tags: python, tkinter, position

When my program runs, the tkinter window covers the output and a camera window, so I was wondering if I could reposition the window elsewhere.

I tried googling for this, but the solutions I found only worked if I used the `from tkinter import tk` or `import tkinter as tk`.They used a `geometry` function. I already have a lot of existing code based on the `from tkinter import *`, so I'm trying to find a way to move the window using the `from tkinter import *`.

Comment: You can call `.geometry()` on the window no matter how you import tkinter.  It is better to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the `geometry` method of the root window. It doesn't matter how you import tkinter.

The `geometry` method takes a string of the form *widthxheight+x+y* and some variations. For example, you can do only *widthxheight* or only *+x+y* and you can use a `-` instead of `+`.

For the complete description of the format see [Geometry strings](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/geometry.html) or the documentation for the [wm geometry](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm#M42) command in the official tcl/tk docs.

You can call this function as often as you like.

The following example makes a window 400 pixels wide, 200 tall, and located at position 100,300.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x200+100+300")

root.mainloop()
```